# Using GlidePalette :java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient

Tags: android, android-studio, android-glide

[image]

I am using Glide library for image loading , I have included following dependencies in build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.github.florent37:glidepalette:1.0.6'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.3.1@aar'
```

Am I missing some thing like dependencies? What kind of issue is this please help me to understand this...!!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing this error behind the scenes, but they way I fixed it is by removing this dependency compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp-integration:1.3.1@aar from the app level build.gradle file. I removed it because glide already comes with OkHttp integration, so it seemed like a duplicate dependency which is potentially what was causing the issue.

Comment: Though it helps to remove errors but functionality of it is not  working properly..any help any one